# multiple calendars of different people on one page using fullcalendar plugin

Tags: jquery

**Description :**

jQuery plugin fullcalendar allows user to show a calender inside a div having an id "calendar"

by the following code we can load the calendar on our page

**HTML**

```
<div id= "calendar" class="calender_box" style="display: hidden; "></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                    header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                     center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },

                    events: '../PHP/get_events.php'
                     });
```

It works perfect!

**After Changing ID's**

**HTML**

```
<div id= "calendar_1" class="calender_box" style="display: hidden; "></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $('#calendar_1').fullCalendar({

                    header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                     center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },

                    events: '../PHP/get_events.php'
                     });
```

Nothing is shown except an empty box

**The Problem :**

I have tried to change the id from `$("#calendar")` to `$("#calendar_1")` but it did'nt work ...

I have a page on which there is picture of a person and below is the icon of calendar when we click the calendar we can see the events of that person ... As far as there is one person it works perfect when the count goes to two I get stuck because there is no other id than "calendar" it accepts and id's are unique so it has to be different for every div ... What should I do ??

Comment: Can you also share the html you are using please?

Comment: Did you mean to add `style="display: hidden;"` ?? That will hide the element, showing an empty box...

Comment: And you only have one <div> and jQuery fullCalendar() call on the page at any one time right?  Can you link to the page if it is public?  No errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to render a calendar in different `<div>` by just using the ID, so:

`$('#calendar_1').fullCalendar({...});`  would go inside `<div id='calendar_1'>` and `$('#calendar_2').fullCalendar({...});` would go inside `<div id='calendar_2'>` and so on.

Another alternative to consider is showing the different persons events on the same calendar using a separate event source for each user.  Not sure what your use case is but might be worth looking into as well:  http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

Comment: $('#calendar_1') this id is not accepted ... only "calender"..
Otherwise the solution you gave is obvious one ... I already did that but it is not working .... 

fullcalender usage page says the following 

 The code relies on there being an element with an id of "calendar" in the body of your page. The calendar will be placed inside this div

Comment: That's not correct, the jquery `$('#calendar').fullCalendar` tells the fullCalendar library to use the dom element with the ID `calendar` for rendering.  If you changed the ID to a different one in both places it will work.  Try it by removing everything from the page except the jquery for fullCalendar setup and a `<div>`, you should be able to use any ID you like

Comment: Yes thats how it is supposed to be! but I am worried that y would it not allow to use a different id ? I have no idea